# Como fazer duas chamadas de arquivos xml no mesmo documento

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml

Gostaria de saber se tem como gerar dois arquivos XML no mesmo documento.

Esse é o código que eu já tenho até o momento:

```
downloadUrl("connect_xml.php", function (data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var rua = markers[i].getAttribute("rua");
        var bairro = markers[i].getAttribute("bairro");
        var CEP = markers[i].getAttribute("CEP");
        var cidade = markers[i].getAttribute("cidade");
        var numero = markers[i].getAttribute("numero");
        var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
        var descricao = markers[i].getAttribute("descricao");

        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        (markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        (markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        //var lat = new google.maps.LatLng
        //(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
       // var lng = new google.maps.LatLng
       // (markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
        var html = "<b>" + rua + "</b> <br/>" + bairro + "</br>" + CEP + "</br>" + cidade + "</br>" + numero + "</br>" + "</br>" + point + "<img width='80' src=" + image + ">" + "</br> <b>" + descricao + "</b>";
        var icon = customIcons[descricao] || {};
        var marker = createMarker(point, rua, bairro, CEP, cidade, numero, image,  descricao, map);
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

    }
    });
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
  clearLocations();


  var searchUrl = 'get_marker.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
  downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
  var xml = parseXml(data);
  var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker1");
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
    var rua = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("rua");
    var bairro = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("bairro");
    var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

    createOption(rua, distance, i);
    createMarker(latlng, rua, bairro);
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
 });
}
```

Comment: coloca mais detalhes, tem algum código iniciado?

Comment: Vai ter de ser mais específico no que pretende.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e paciência galera!!
Então, como vocês podem ver acima, eu tenho esses dois códigos que me geram marcadores em um mapa, porém o primeiro consegue me passar esse marker, mas o segundo não, existe algum tipo de conflito, posso usar a mesma função de retorno para os dois?

Comment: E um problema que está acontecendo, quando eu coloco os dois pra rodar, e chama a função de criar o marcador no segundo xml, ele sobrepõe o primeiro.